# How to change the WMS Background Color in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I am using geoserver to serve up an image pyramid basemap.  I want to have all areas outside of the data extent be black (instead of white).

I have the map displayed inside of a div tag and changing the css on that tag or the container (another div) it resides in has no effect.  I have checked both the geoserver and openlayers documentation, but have not seen any way to change the background color.

Any suggestions on where to continue searching?  Do I need to generate a black tiles and serve them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can set the background color in the WMS request, using the BGCOLOR param, with a hex value. Example: `&BGCOLOR=0x000000`

Comment: Is there a configuration parameter in geoserver like "wms_bgcolor" (metadata) in mapserver?

Comment: @fherdom, no there isn't, that would probably violate the WMS specification (it states the background color is white unless explicitly indicated by the client)

Answer (score 13):

In the definition of the WMS layer in your OpenLayers JavaScript code, you can specify the parameter **bgcolor**. This will eventually add the BGCOLOR parameter to the URL to the WMS service as explained already. For example:

```
var osm = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
    "OpenStreetMap",
    url,
    {
        width: '600',
        height: '400',
        srs: 'EPSG:3857',
        layers: 'OpenStreetMap',
        styles: '',
        format: 'image/png',
        bgcolor: '0x80BDE3'
     },
     {
        singleTile: true,
        ratio: 1,
        visibility: true,
        isBaseLayer: true
    }
);
```

Comment: Spot on and a slightly more complete answer as someone might not be totally sure where to add the parameter.  Thanks!