# MapServer WMS background color in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, wms, mapserver, style

I am using MapServer to render a number of layers and then I'm setting it up as a WMS server in order to render it using OpenLayers 3. I want the background color of the image to be grey so I set it with the following snippet:

```
MAP
 EXTENT 300000.000 4374000.000 316000.000 4386000.000
  UNITS meters
  SIZE 900 580
  IMAGETYPE png
  IMAGECOLOR 240 237 229
  ...
```

So in CGI mode it behaves as expected rendering the background as grey. However the same does not happen with OpenLayers. I'm setting params to render it as 'image/png':

```
var params = {
            LAYERS : 'layer1, layer2,layer3...layerN',
            FORMAT : 'image/png'
     }
```

Setting FORMAT as 'image/png' makes the background color white instead of the grey I want. If I set FORMAT as 'image/jpeg' the the background color turns to total black. So how can I keep the same grey color using OpenLayers?

Which format do I need to use?

Comment: With WMS you should be able to set the background color dynamically with &BGCOLOR parameter `Hexadecimal red-green-blue color value for the
background color (default=0xFFFFFF)`. See this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20313/how-to-change-the-wms-background-color-in-openlayers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, areas outside of the layers of a WMS are set as transparent by OpenLayers.

So add this:

```
var params = {
   transparent : false   
 }
```

in your variable params. Works for me.

J.

Comment: Yup... !!! That's it..!!!  I'ts working ^_^  Thank you

Comment: One more question, regarding the CRS of the WMS service: is there a default CRS (in OpenLayers case 3857) when you use your WMS service through OpenLayers?  Cause I've set my mapfile with PROJECTION object to be "init=epsg:2100" and of course "wms_srs" to "EPSG:2100". However when I try to load it and examine the Network tab of the page, my WMS service is loaded with EPSG 3857. How's that possible ?

Comment: Indeed, it seems that OpenLayers set a default CRS of EPSG:3857. I tried to override this in the variable `params` by setting CRS : 'EPSG:2100' or even SRS: 'EPSG:2100' but it seems that OpenLayers ignored them.

Comment: So is there any solution to this?  Because otherwise this means that if I have other data in another EPSG I cannot have them both in a View.., right?

Comment: Also is it just me or reprojecting a WMS service causes a bluring effect on the image ?